# Equation of motion for two bodies attracting each other

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism

I'm trying to find the Lagrangian and the equation of motion for two bodies attracting each other by gravitational force. The centre of mass of the system is taken as the origin.

The Lagrangian is 
\begin{align}
L&=T-V \\
 &=\frac{1}{2}m_{1}\dot{r}_{1}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m_{2}\dot{r}_{2}^2 + \frac{Gm_{1}m_{2}}{(r_{1}+r_{2})} \\
\end{align}
where $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ are the distances from the centre of mass of the system to the bodies $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ respectively.

Since $m_{1}r_{1}=m_{2}r_{2}$,
\begin{align}
L=\frac{1}{2}m_{1}\dot{r}_{1}^2 \bigg( 1+\frac{m_{1}}{m_{2}} \bigg) + 
\frac{Gm_{1}m_{2}}{\big(1+\frac{m_{1}}{m_{2}}\big)r_{1}}
\end{align}
The equation of motion is
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r}_{1}}\bigg)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial r_{1}} &= 0 \\
m_{1}\ddot{r}_{1} \bigg( 1+\frac{m_{1}}{m_{2}} \bigg) + 
\frac{Gm_{1}m_{2}}{\big(1+\frac{m_{1}}{m_{2}}\big)r_{1}^2} &=0 \\
m_{1}\ddot{r}_{1} = -\frac{Gm_{1}m_{2}}{\big(1+\frac{m_{1}}{m_{2}}\big)^2 r_{1}^2}
\end{align}
However, in the book, the answer is given as
\begin{align}
m_{1}\ddot{r}_{1} = -\frac{Gm_{1}m_{2}}{\big(1+\frac{m_{1}}{m_{2}}\big) r_{1}^2}
\end{align}

Is my answer right? Is the potential term in the Lagrangian right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Your result is correct, it is probably just a typo in your book

Comment: i agree with caverac...your result is right